# Store array of items in SQL table

Tags: sql, arrays

I know this has probably been asked a million times but I can't find anything definite for me. I'm making a website involving users who can build a list of items. I'm wondering what would be the best way for store their items in an SQL table?

I'm thinking will I need to make a seperate table for each user since there I can't see any way to store an array. I think this would be inefficient however.

Comment: "I'm making a website involving users who can build a list of items" It's not possible to describe your requirement vaguer.

Comment: I'm using wamp so MYSQL? Nothing is set in stone yet. It is only to run on my local machine.

Comment: @TimSchmelter haha sorry. It is a website where you can build up a shopping list pretty much. You can go on and make a grocery list for that week.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on what an "item" is, there seem to be two possible solutions:

1. a one-to-many relationship between users and items
2. a many-to-many relationship between users and items

If a single item (such as a "book") can be "assigned" to more than one user, it's 2). If each item is unique and can only belong to a single user it's 1).

### one-to-many relationship

```
create table users
(
   user_id    integer primary key not null,
   username   varchar(100) not null
);

create table items
(
   item_id    integer primary key not null,
   user_id    integer not null references users(user_id),
   item_name  varchar(100) not null
);
```

### many-to-many relationship:

```
create table users
(
   user_id    integer primary key not null,
   username   varchar(100) not null
);

create table items
(
   item_id    integer primary key not null,
   item_name  varchar(100) not null
);

create table user_items
(
    user_id   integer not null references users(user_id),
    item_id   integer not null references items(item_id)
);
```

Because of your extremely vague description, this is the best I can think of.

There is no need to use an array or something similar. It seems you are new to database modelling, so you should read up about normalisation. Each time you think about "arrays" you are probably thinking about "tables" (or relations).

**Edit (just saw you mentioned MySQL):**
 the above SQL will **not** create a foreign key constraint in MySQL (even though it will run without an error) due to MySQL's stupid "I'm not telling you if I can't do something" attitude. You need to define the foreign keys separately.

Comment: Sorry about the vague description. I'm making a website where users can create groceries lists. Each user will have a different list. So each user will have a list of items. I'm trying to see what is the best way to design my database. Also yes, I am new enough to database modelling.

Comment: My website will not have many users at all. But in theory, if 1000 users had over 100 items. Does that mean that the user_items table would be 1000*100 rows?

Comment: @user1375026: yes. But that is a pretty small table.

Comment: Cool. Thanks very much for that, great help. I was about to create a separate table for each user. Great help again.

Answer (score 0):

A separate table for each user\account would be best. This will limit the size of the necessary tables and allow for faster searching. When you present data you are usually displaying data for that current user/account. When you have to search through the table to find the relative information. The application will start to slow down the larger the dependent table grows. Write the application as if it will be used to the fullest extent of SQL. This will limit the need for redesign in the future if the website becomes popular.